# Filter output as a variable

Tags: boto3, amazon-eks

I am writing a CloudFormation template that needs a custom wait. In order for this to work I need the Update ID of the first task being run.

The response I get is, `{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'f95a182a-9908-11e9-a8b8-2967c8573c31', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Thu, 27 Jun 2019 18:25:44 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '313', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'f95a182a-9908-11e9-a8b8-2967c8573c31', 'x-amz-apigw-id': 'b86GJE-lCYcF1qw=', 'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-5d150a27-cc9c3290fba93939d77af990'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'update': {'id': 'cf86b57c-c1a9-4a72-8828-01dd786e171f', 'status': 'InProgress', 'type': 'LoggingUpdate', 'params': [{'type': 'ClusterLogging', 'value': '{"clusterLogging":[{"types":["api","audit","authenticator","controllerManager","scheduler"],"enabled":true}]}'}], 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 27, 13, 25, 43, 853000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'errors': []}}`

the two key attributes I am looking to filter is id and status. I have tried update.id, `update`,`id`, updateID and [update][1][id] and all of them give me a key error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those using

```
response['update']['id']
response['update']['status']
```